# Move TextField containing widget to view-able area when keyboard pop up regardless of another widget in the bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

What am trying to achieve is move my TextField to view-able area when keyboard pop up, also I want a widget(Text widget) that is aligned bottom center to remain in there and get hidden by keyboard.

My Code:

```
     @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     //databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
    return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('BOM'),
    ),
    body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[ 
            //SingleChildScrollView widget tried here, result was a failure

        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selection = '5-co';
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 130.0,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: selection == '5-co'
                                  ? Colors.green
                                  : Colors.black45,
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            'COMPONENTS',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 13.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 30.0,
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selection = '5-nl';
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 130.0,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: selection == '5-nl'
                                  ? Colors.blue
                                  : Colors.black45,
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            'REXIN',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 13.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // SizedBox(height: 50,),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter article:',
                      hintText: 'eg: 3290-BR',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.local_offer),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //if (value.length >= 4) {
                            navigateToList(controller.text, selection);
                            //  } else
                            //   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            //    content:
                            //
                          }),
                      /*enabledBorder:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),*/
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                    ),
                    onSubmitted: (value) {
                      //if (value.length >= 4) {
                      navigateToList(value, selection);
                      //  } else
                      //   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      //    content:
                      //     Text('Oops, please give me more details !')));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(' P  A  N  D  U',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      fontSize: 30.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ))
      ]));
    }));
}
```

Currently my **TextField** containing widget is in a **container** under **stack widget** and is aligned to center by **column widget** attribs.

**WHAT I TRIED:**
I referred some questions in here and tried  **SingleChildScrollView widget** under my stack, and result was my **container** under the  **SingleChildScrollView widget** loses its column axis attribs and get aligned to top of body.

What I didn't tried to solve my issue is with animations to move widget up. I will go for it if there isn't any other method, cause I gotta learn about those widgets which is still in que. ;')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made `SingleChildScrollView` widget under my stack for all my widgets except the bottom w`Text` widget, which I don't want to see when keyboard pops up. And then I just hide my `Text` widget using flutter's `Visibility` widget when keyboard comes in screen. This completely solved my problem (*I used `keyboard_visibility: ^0.5.5` library to get keyboard info, that tells when to hide or show my Text widget in the bottom* ).

**For reference my unsorted whole code:**

```
   bool _visible = true;

    @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
   KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
  onChange: (bool keyvisible) {
    //print('keyboard $visible');
    setState(() {
      _visible = !keyvisible;
    });
  },
);
}

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
return Scaffold(
    //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('BOM'),
    ),
    body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          //margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 200.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selection = '5-co';
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 130.0,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: selection == '5-co'
                                    ? Colors.green
                                    : Colors.black45,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              'COMPONENTS',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 13.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 30.0,
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selection = '5-nl';
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 130.0,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: selection == '5-nl'
                                    ? Colors.blue
                                    : Colors.black45,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              'REXIN',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 13.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // SizedBox(height: 50,),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                      controller: controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Enter article:',
                        hintText: 'eg: 3290-BR',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.local_offer),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            onPressed: () {
                              //if (value.length >= 4) {
                              navigateToList(controller.text, selection);
                              //  } else
                              //   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                              //    content:
                              //
                            }),
                        /*enabledBorder:
                OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0), borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),*/
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                      ),
                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                        //if (value.length >= 4) {
                        navigateToList(value, selection);
                        //  } else
                        //   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        //    content:
                        //     Text('Oops, please give me more details !')));
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Visibility(
                visible: _visible,
                child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                      text: ' P  A  N  D  U',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      TextSpan(text: '\t v', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      TextSpan(text: '0.02.05', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 11.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic))
                ])),
              ),
            ))
      ]));
    }));
 }
```

Comment: I am using 0.5.6 of keyboard_visibilty. it only calls callback when widget is drawn for the first time and never emit events again.